# AWS Chime SDK video doesn't work on mobile

Tags: amazon-web-services, mobile, aws-sdk, aws-chime-sdk

I built a demo Chime app using the SDK, I used this demo to deploy it:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/business-productivity/building-a-meeting-application-using-the-amazon-chime-sdk/

When I test it on mobile and try turning on the video, it flashes on and off very quickly and doesn't stay on.
I'm not sure why it does this and I am wondering if anyone could help me out or has any ideas.

Comment: Add the chimemeeting browserlogs her